# Can't seem to make python celery signals work

Tags: python, celery

I'm rather new to celery development and I have an issue implementing signals.
I have an application that consists of many different workers.
currently it uses rabbitmq as a broker and redis as a backend.

Each worker has its own queue. This is the way we have it configured at the moment :

```
celery = Celery(queueDict['test'], broker=config.REDIS_SERVER, backend=config.REDIS_SERVER)
default_exchange = Exchange('default', type='direct')
test_queue = Queue(queueDict['test'], default_exchange, routing_key=queueDict['test'])


logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

celery.conf.task_queues = (test_queue, )


@celery.task(name='signal2', bind=True)
def signal2(self, param):
    print("dog" + param)
```

I would like to use signals so that I will be able to catch failed tasks on any worker in the application. When I use it inside the same worker with a task_failure event it works.
But I would like to have another worker catch these events (or even my flask app)
but I seem to be missing something...
Here is my current attempt at making it work.

```
celery = Celery('consumer', broker=config.REDIS_SERVER, backend=config.REDIS_SERVER)
default_exchange = Exchange('default', type='direct')
default_queue = Queue(queueDict['default'], default_exchange, routing_key=queueDict['default'])

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

celery.conf.task_queues = (default_queue, )


@task_failure.connect
def process_failure_signal(sender=None, task_id=None, exception=None,
                           args=None, kwargs=None, traceback=None, einfo=None, **akwargs):

    msg = 'Signal exception: %s (%s)' % (
        exception.__class__.__name__, exception)
    exc_info = (type(exception), exception, traceback)
    extra = {
        'data': {
            'task_id': str(task_id),
            'sender': str(sender),
            'args': str(args),
            'kwargs': str(kwargs),
        }
    }

    logger.error(msg, exc_info=exc_info, extra=extra)
```

But it never receives any signals...
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I never used `task_failure` but I use app.events.Receiver to implement my own monitoring system that we use in production - here is what helped me start: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing

Comment: I will look into it. 
Looks good.

Answer (score 0):

DejanLekic was correct and the page he shared had exactly what I wanted.

for those interested:
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing

This can be easily used to capture events and monitor tasks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Real-time processing

To process events in real-time you need the following

- An event consumer (this is the `Receiver`)
- A set of handlers called when events come in.

  > You can have different handlers for each event type, or a catch-all handler can be used ('*')
- State (optional)

  `app.events.State` is a convenient in-memory representation of tasks and workers in the cluster that’s updated as events come in.

  It encapsulates solutions for many common things, like checking if a worker is still alive (by verifying heartbeats), merging event fields together as events come in, making sure time-stamps are in sync, and so on.

Combining these you can easily process events in real-time:

```py
from celery import Celery

def my_monitor(app):
    state = app.events.State()

    def announce_failed_tasks(event):
        state.event(event)
        # task name is sent only with -received event, and state
        # will keep track of this for us.
        task = state.tasks.get(event['uuid'])

        print('TASK FAILED: %s[%s] %s' % (
            task.name, task.uuid, task.info(),))

    with app.connection() as connection:
        recv = app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
                'task-failed': announce_failed_tasks,
                '*': state.event,
        })
        recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Celery(broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
    my_monitor(app)
```

**Note**: The `wakeup` argument to `capture` sends a signal to all workers to force them to send a heartbeat. This way you can immediately see workers when the monitor starts.

You can listen to specific events by specifying the handlers:

```py
from celery import Celery

def my_monitor(app):
    state = app.events.State()

    def announce_failed_tasks(event):
        state.event(event)
        # task name is sent only with -received event, and state
        # will keep track of this for us.
        task = state.tasks.get(event['uuid'])

        print('TASK FAILED: %s[%s] %s' % (
            task.name, task.uuid, task.info(),))

    with app.connection() as connection:
        recv = app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
                'task-failed': announce_failed_tasks,
        })
        recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Celery(broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
    my_monitor(app)
```

<sub>[Monitoring and Management Guide — Celery 4.4.2 documention](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing)</sub>